# Transaction Sent Taking almost 2 days , what's wrong? Help pls

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

i'm very confused, i sent some btc almost 2 days a go using the default fee and it hasn't gone thru, what could be causing this? 
Has never happened before, since this i've already put the fee on max and other transactions works but this one still isn't going thru...
BlockChain Link: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/e94022faf0fbdea8ef413237cd53498e73977830f9b8284183be87dc958ac919

is it stuck? can i do something to fix this?

Any Help is welcome, will be willing to tip if someone helps with the case..

Answer (score 0):

For the block [441662](https://blockchain.info/fr/block/000000000000000003372e78de192754ae0d6ceff1333f9dd5dc6fee05ee3b0b?show_adv=true), actual block, the medium fees are around 0.0007 BTC per a transaction's size equal to 226 byte.

Your transaction has 0.0001 BTC as fees for a transaction's size equal to 520 byte.

So, miners will ignore your transaction until one of them pick it up in his block or stay ignored and finally refused (if it'll take a long time or if there is something with your transaction) and the coin will return to the sender.

You can also [rebrocast your transaction](https://blog.blockchain.com/2014/07/08/tutorial-how-to-rebroadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction/) again untill it'll be confirmed as soon as possible.

Next time try to put more fees in order to have fast confirmations.